# How to save child object automatically using a parent object using Hibernate and JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have onetoone association. The child class has a foreign key which is a primary key in the parent class. My problem is I am unable to save the object of child class with the parent class.

My add method is as follows:

```
@Transactional
public void add(ParentDTO parentDTO) {
    parentDTO.setChild(child);
    child.setParent(parentDTO);
    Parent parent = mapper.map(parentDTO, Parent.class);
    parentRepository.save(parent);
}
```

JSP code is as follows;

```
<form:form action="user.do" method="POST" commandName="user">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User ID</td>
        <td><form:input path="userId" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td><form:checkbox path="active" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><form:label path="ethnicity.ethnicityId" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nationality</td>
        <td><form:input path="ethnicity.nationality" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Race</td>
        <td><form:input path="ethnicity.race" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Region</td>
        <td><form:input path="ethnicity.region" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Religion</td>
        <td><form:input path="ethnicity.religion" /></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute UserDTO user,
        BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action,
        Map<String, Object> map){
    UserDTO userResult = new UserDTO();
    switch(action.toLowerCase()){
    case "add":
        userService.add(user);
        break;
```

Comment: Check your cascade option

Comment: @Naman cascade option is cascade=CascadeType.ALL for both the entities.

I am able to save the foreign key in child but not the other attributes of child class.

Comment: Have you set other attribute of child? In this implementation it is not visible that where you are initializing child and setting property

Comment: `childDTO.setNationality(childDTO.getNationality());`

I tried to save it like this but unable to save but when I try to hard code it like `childDTO.setNationality("xyz");` then the attribute got the value. Can you explain how to save the values dynamically.

Comment: What are you doing in childDTO.getNationality()

Comment: I have added one answer that may be useful as you have not provided implementation of your child object

Comment: Actually I want all this dynamically, do not want to hard code it. Here I am trying to get the value which I am setting using the .jsp page.

Comment: Can you show that how you are getting those values from jsp. As I can see that you are not actually getting it exact way. Are you using jsp/servlet or spring controller?

Comment: On the jsp I am doing like;
`<tr>
    <td>Nationality</td>
    <td><form:input path="ethnicity.nationality" /></td>
</tr>` to save the value.

Comment: I am using spring controller not the servlet. Can you please tell how can I get the value.

Comment: I am doing this as I told u earlier but I am unable to get the value for Nationality.

Comment: Have you used commandname as ethnicity in <form:form> tag?

Comment: The command name is "user" in the <form:from> tag. Here the ethnicityDTO is object of the (child) class ethnicityDTO which I initialize in the service implementation class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using spring form so in controller you will get your ethnicity object in model attribute.

you can go like as below :

```
childDTO.setNationality(user.getEthnicity().getNationality());
```

If you are using servlet you can get value with

```
childDTO.setNationality(request.getParameter("nationality"));
```

And in Spring controller there are other ways as well to get your jsp input:

```
   @Transactional
    public void add(ParentDTO parentDTO) {
//your child object should have all the property set here so that all values will be automatically inserted.
parentDTO.setChild(child);
child.setParent(parentDTO);
Parent parent = mapper.map(parentDTO, Parent.class);
parentRepository.save(parent);
//Even you can set property here
```

}

Comment: `ethnicityDTO.setNationality(ethnicityDTO.getNationality());` is unable to retrieve the value.

Comment: I edited this: childDTO.setNationality(user.getEthnicity.getNationality());

Comment: Tried this but I am getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException" exception.

Comment: And where you have written code to set nationality?

Comment: The setters and getters are in the model and DTO class. In the service class just want to get those vlaues.

Comment: Manage to solve it, but not sure is it right approach or not. What I did is first get a value in a string `String nationality = userDTO.getEthnicity().getNationality();` and then try to set the value like `ethnicity.setNationality(nationality);`

Answer (score 0):

Inspect/debug the Parent object after mapper call. `Parent parent = mapper.map(parentDTO, Parent.class);`   Is it mapping complete child data ?

Comment: I have debug but the child object is NULL and that's the problem.

Comment: You may be using some kind of mapper framework, verify the configuration ( probably mapping xml) for mapping ParentDTO to Parent class. I may not be able to help further.

Comment: I am using annotations.